# How to import annual statement data?

Tags: r, import, finance, yfinance

I am unable to import annual statement of a company from a website.

I tried quantmod for importing financial data but it's not working.

Comment: What type of file is the annual statement? Quantmod supports OHLC and FX data, tabular (e.g. csv), and some database sources.

Comment: Annual Statement file (Profit & Loss, Balance Sheet). Quantmod is unable to import income statement data from google.

Comment: Your question provides very little useful info. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?r=Saves_AllUserSaves   Then use the "Edit" function on your question to add the information suggested in the link.